# reactjs, passing functionality from third component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have this BarsGenerator component.**

```
const BarsGenerator = () => {

const { sliderValue } = useContext(GlobalState); // get slider value from global state
const [bars, setBars] = useState<number[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const randomArray = RandomNumberGenerator(sliderValue!, 10, 200);
    setBars(randomArray);
}, [sliderValue]);

const barsList = bars.map((bar, index) => {
    return <Bar key={index} height={bar} value={`${bar}`} />
});

return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "70px" }} className="bars-container">
        {barsList}
    </div>
);
```

**And a Sidebar component.**

```
const Sidebar = () => {
return (
    <div className="sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar-header">
            <h4>CONTROLS</h4>
            <hr style={hrStyles.hrStyle_one} />
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-content">
            <div className="sidebar-content-item">

                <h6>ALGORITHM</h6>
                <Selectbox />

                <hr style={hrStyles.hrStyle_two} />

                <h6 style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>SLIDERS</h6>

                <div className="sliders">
                    <Slider />
                </div>

                <div className="sliders">
                    <Slider />
                </div>

                <hr style={hrStyles.hrStyle_two} />

                <Button name='Sort' />
                <Button name='Generate' />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

I want to create a new component from where i can pass a already created sort function to the `Button` component in the `sidebar` component above.

But I can't figure it out how to do so or if is it even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that?

```
const NewComponent = () => {
  const sort = () => {
    // sorting
  };

  const generate = () => {
    // generating
  };

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button name='Sort' onPress={sort} />
      <Button name='Generate' onPress={generate} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default NewComponent;
```

```
const Sidebar = () => {
return (
    <div className="sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar-header">
            <h4>CONTROLS</h4>
            <hr style={hrStyles.hrStyle_one} />
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-content">
            <div className="sidebar-content-item">

                <h6>ALGORITHM</h6>
                <Selectbox />

                <hr style={hrStyles.hrStyle_two} />

                <h6 style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>SLIDERS</h6>

                <div className="sliders">
                    <Slider />
                </div>

                <div className="sliders">
                    <Slider />
                </div>

                <hr style={hrStyles.hrStyle_two} />

                <NewComponent />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

**UPDATE**

Please tweak it according to your needs

Context File

```
import {createContext} from "react";

export const GlobalState = createContext({
    bars: [],
    setBars: () => {

    },
    getBars: () => {

    }
});
```

Custom Hook File

```
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from "react";

export const useBars = () => {
  const [bars, setBars] = useState([]);

  const setBars = useCallback((bars) => {
    setBars(bars);
  }, []);

  const unsetBars = useCallback(() => {
    setBars([]);
  }, []);

  return {bars, setBars, unsetBars}
};
```

App File

```
import {useBars} from "./shared/hooks/bars-hook"; //custom hook file

const App = () => {
  const {bars, setBars, unsetBars} = useBars();
  //your other code
  //your other code
  //...

  return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{/* your other code */bars: bars, setBars: setBars, unsetBars: unsetBars}}
      >
        {/*your other code*/}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

BarsGenerator File

```
//your other code
import {GlobalState} from "../../shared/context/bars-context"; //context file
//your other code

const BarsGenerator = () => {
  const bars = useContext(GlobalState);
  //your other code
  useEffect(() => {
    const randomArray = RandomNumberGenerator(sliderValue!, 10, 200);
    setBars(randomArray);
    //add this one
    bars.setBars(randomArray);
    //add this one
  }, [sliderValue]);
  //your other code
};
```

New Component File

```
import {GlobalState} from "../../shared/context/bars-context"; 

const NewComponent = () => {
  const bars = useContext(GlobalState);

  const sort = () => {
    // sorting
    // NOW YOU CAN USE THIS -> bars.bars
  };

  const generate = () => {
    // generating
  };

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button name='Sort' onPress={sort} />
      <Button name='Generate' onPress={generate} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default NewComponent;
```

Comment: But the problem is how to import the generated bars from from the `barsGenerator` component to apply sort on them.

Comment: Can you use GlobalState in BarsGenerator component to save the bars and then reach them in the new component using GlobalState again?

Something like:
import {createContext} from "react";
export const AuthContext = createContext({bars:[]}); Of course, you can edit your Global Context.

Comment: yes that's possible i even thought of that before but that somehow doesn't seem to be a proper way to me it results in to much messed up code. I can get all the elements with class name **bar** like this `const bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')` and that would solve everything in a easy way. But that doesn't seems like a react way of doing it.

Comment: Making a custom hook with setBars method would be an elegant solution. You can call this hook in your App component and inject its setBars method into AuthContext.Provider. After you should edit your GlobalState context file to include this method with empty body. Now you are set to use setBars method inside BarsGenerator component. Similar to setBars, you should have implemented getBars component. As a result, in the new component, you can call getBars method to get the bars and do stuff like sorting.

Comment: It does seem a nice way can you provide some examples with code. To get started with.

Comment: Please check the updated answer